# Heroku - deployment of spring+angular application code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: java, angular, spring, heroku

I am trying to deploy springboot application with embedded angular.
I can see on heroku, that maven build and deploy ends with success but when I try to see the page, I'm getting this error:

[Maven build and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMKEx.png)

> heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=haro-poker.herokuapp.com fwd="89.64.58.71" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

which tells me completely nothing. My Procfile points to war, which already contain compiled angular files:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ./backend/target/backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.

I am able to run the app with this command locally but there is some kind of problem on heroku. I'm trying to solve it whole day. Maybe do you know what may cause the problem? Can I run app in debug mode to see more logs?
Application github: https://github.com/piotrkosinski1992/haro-poker

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Based on your linked repo, I assume you were able to fix your problem?

Comment: Yes. One of  those environment variables in Procfile has to be mandatory: -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS. When I've added those, problem was fixed

Comment: Yeah, for future readers: you need to bind to the port Heroku gives you via the $PORT environment variable.